# Can decentralised systems mitigate 51% attacks by design?

Tags: distributed-systems

Can you make interesting decentralised systems, e.g. cryptocurrencies or serverless games, that aren't susceptible to 51% attacks by design? (Rather than, as I've seen proposed, external solutions like fining mining pools that have too large a hashing power)

Comment: what about PoS systems?

Comment: @user253751 it's not immdiately obvious to me how to build a serverless game or other decentralised network on top of a PoS system

Comment: The question seems vague.  What properties do you want the systems to have?  What's the definition of a "51% attack" specifically?  I can make decentralized systems that aren't subject to any attack: e.g., if each node is required to output the number 42 at each time step, that is easy to accomplish.

Comment: @D.W. "cryptocurrencies or serverless (peer-to-peer) games"